# Grid Gain web console failed to find JDBC driver.?

Tags: sql, ignite, gridgain, web-console

I am connecting my NodeJs project to ignite. I have configure cluster and connect Web Console Agent but when I click on Import Database button I get following error.

```
Agent Failed to find JDBC driver
Copy required JDBC driver into 'jdbc-drivers' folder and try again
```

Can anyone guide from where I can get jdbc driver.

I also study README file inside jdbc folder (Web console agent), but unable to understand from where i will get jdbc driver and paste there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC driver is a part of your database. What database engine are you using? Typically they have JDBC driver as a separate download.

Comment: I am using inno db (my sql).

Comment: I downloaded jdbc driver seperately and copy the jdbc file in JDBC folder inside agent.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?